# What exactly does this WSO2 ESB echo endpoint?

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb

I am very new in **WSO2** and I have the following doubt related to an **ESB** project on which I am working.

In this ESB application I am sending a message to a **named endopoint** mediator, something like this:

```
<send>
    <endpoint key="echoEndpoint"/>
</send>
```

This is the contend of the related **echoEndpoint.xml** file in my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="echoEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address format="soap11" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri="http://localhost:8280/services/echo"/>
</endpoint>
```

So what exactly does this endpoint? The **http://localhost:8280/services/echo** is something like a predefined endopoined provided natively by WSO2? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo service included into esb/ei by default. You can see it in Carbon Panel -> Main -> Manage -> Services. There you can test it via "Try It" feature. It has few methods:

- echoInt extected to get integer as argument and returned same integer value
- echoString - expected to get string value as argument and returned same value
- echoOMElement - received XML as argument and returned same XML

and some other methods. General idea - this service returned same value as it is received.

This service is helpful for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a service that by default is already displayed when you run the ESB. Echo.aar is located in the path repository\deployment\server\axis2services . And wsdl you can see https://localhost:your_Port/services/echo?wsdl